# Error while migrating data from oracle to cassandra using ./dse sqoop cql-import

Tags: sqoop

I am getting following error while migrating oracle data to cassandra using DSE SQOOP.

Below is the command and error stack:

> ./dse sqoop cql-import --table USERS --columns firstname
>   --cassandra-keyspace ORCL --cassandra-table USERS --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/xxxx@//us01u245:1521/orcldb --cassandra-host
>   us01u246
>
> ERROR 01:04:27 Encountered IOException running import job:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to read the table metadata
>           at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.SqoopUtil.setCqlImportOptions(SqoopUtil.java:219)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.CqlImportJob.configureOutputFormat(CqlImportJob.java:79)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:240)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.SqlManagerAdapter.importTable(SqlManagerAdapter.java:236)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:601)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
>           at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:57) Caused by: java.io.IOException: No table metadata found for ORCL.USERS
>           at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.SqoopUtil.setCqlImportOptions(SqoopUtil.java:161)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle schema name might be missing before table name. Also check the oracle  table columns and cassandra table columns. They are case sensitive.